# Android Navigation JetPack + BottomNavigationView + nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Do you have any example app that uses BottomNavigatationView with Navigation Component and includes nested fragment? I want to create an app with 3 tabs (A, B, C) in BottomNavigationView and each tab is related to fragment that containes nested fragment.

tab A: Frag A1 -> Frag A2 -> Frag A3, tab B: Frag B1 -> Frag B2, tab C: Frag C1 -> Frag C2.

Default implementation from Android Developers has some issues and doesn't work properly (according to BottomNavigationView material behavior):

1. Clicking on active tab in bottom nav triggers recreating fragment (it should not do that).
2. I select a tab (ex. tab B), move to nested fragment (ex. Frag B2), then select tab A and click again on tab B then Frag B1 is visible (not Frag B2 as I expected).

Do you have any solution for working that properly out of the box?

Comment: Did you find any solution to that?

Comment: Sure! Default implementation of AndroidX Navigation works perfectly. I have one fragment that contains NavHostFragment and bottom navigation view related to this graph. And then in navigation.xml I have implemented fragments for each tab. Every "tab fragment" is wrapper for further NavHostFragment. This way I achived switching between tabs and handling nested graph for each tab

Comment: @piotrpawlowski can we have sample code?